# why the style that i give with event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling

i give the background style and when i click on the element the color will change but right after that it get back to the previous color

```
navListMenuItems.map(
({ icon, title, description, id }, key) => (
  < a  href="#" key={key} >
    <MenuItem onClick={ (event) => {
      event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'salmon'
      }} className="flex items-center gap-3 rounded-lg hover:bg-lightbluebg py-[8px] pl-[20px]">
      <div  className={key === 0 ? "w-[43px] flex items-center justify-center rounded-[50%] !bg-naviconpurple p-2" : (key == 1 ? "w-[43px] flex items-center justify-center rounded-[50%] !bg-navicondarkblue2x p-2" : (key == 2 ? "w-[43px] flex items-center justify-center rounded-[50%] !bg-naviconorange p-2" : (key == 3 ? "w-[43px] flex items-center justify-center rounded-[50%] !bg-naviconlightblue p-2" : (key == 4 ? "w-[43px] flex items-center justify-center rounded-[50%] !bg-navicongreen p-2" : (key == 5 ? "w-[43px] flex items-center justify-center rounded-[50%] !bg-navicondarkblue2x p-2" : (key == 6 ? "w-[43px] flex items-center justify-center rounded-[50%] !bg-naviconorange p-2" : (key == 7 ? "w-[43px] flex items-center justify-center rounded-[50%] !bg-naviconpurple p-2" : (key == 8 ? "w-[43px] flex items-center justify-center rounded-[50%] !bg-navicongreen p-2" : (key == 9 ? "w-[43px] flex items-center justify-center rounded-[50%] !bg-navicondarkblue2x p-2" : (key == 10 ? "w-[43px] flex items-center justify-center rounded-[50%] !bg-naviconorange p-2" : "w-[43px] flex items-center justify-center rounded-[50%] !bg-naviconpurple p-2"))))))))))}>

        {" "}
        {React.createElement(icon, {
          strokeWidth: 1,
          className: "h-6 text-mainblack w-6 text-white border-none",
        })}
      </div>
      <div>
        <h6

          className="flex items-center text-sm font-bold transition-colors ease duration-300 text-[15px]"
        >
          {title}
        </h6>
        <p
          className="text-xs !font-medium text-textgrey mt-1"
        >
          {description}
        </p>
      </div>
    </MenuItem>
  </a >
),
```

Comment: You need a way to persist the event change by holding it in state. Can you share the full component/page code snippet? I want to confirm if you're currently holding the value in state but mutating directly.